# how to convert to specific value when input is in binary string format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a situation, where i will get a string like days varchar(7), days='1001101'
I want to produce an output like 
1:sunday 
0:absent
0:absent
1:wensday
1:thursday
0:abset
1:saturday

final output:sunday wensday thursday saturday 
How can I achieve it by using T-SQL function. (Function with input output parameter)

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: i am trying to solve it by using case

Comment: Use @Pradeep answer since function will simply do the job for you, else have a look at the code using CASE stmt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create function dateconvert(@input varchar(100))
returns varchar(1000)
begin
declare 
@i int=1,
@temp varchar(1000)='',
@output1 varchar(1000)='',
@output varchar(1000)
while (@i<=len(@input))
    begin
        set @temp = substring(@input, @i, 1)
        set @output= ( select  case
                               when @temp = '1'
                                    and @i = 1 then 'sunday'
                               when @temp = '1'
                                    and @i = 2 then 'monday'
                               when @temp = '1'
                                    and @i = 3 then 'tuesday'
                               when @temp = '1'
                                    and @i = 4 then 'wednesday'
                               when @temp = '1'
                                    and @i = 5 then 'thursday'
                               when @temp = '1'
                                    and @i = 6 then 'friday'
                               when @temp = '1'
                                    and @i = 7 then 'saturday'
                               else '_'
                             end )
            set @output1=@output1+@output
            set @i = @i + 1 
    end
    return @output1
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `CHOOSE function` to get the result. Try this..

**Note :** This will work only in SQL SERVER 2012+.. If you want to use it on earlier version just use `Case statements` instead of `Choose`. Just to simply the code i have used `CHOOSE function`

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Func (@dayss VARCHAR(1000))
returns VARCHAR(1000)
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @cnt    INT =1,
              @outpt  VARCHAR(100),
              @fina   VARCHAR(100)='',
              @outpt1 VARCHAR(100)=''

      WHILE @cnt <= Len(@dayss)
        BEGIN
            SET @outpt = Substring(@dayss, @cnt, 1)

            SELECT @outpt1 = CASE
                               WHEN @outpt = 1 THEN @outpt
                                                    + Choose(@cnt, ':sunday ', ':monday ', ':tuesday ', ':wednesday ', ':thursday ', ':friday ', ':saturday ')
                               ELSE @outpt + ':absent '
                             END

            SET @fina += @outpt1
            SET @cnt+=1
        END

      RETURN @fina
  END

SELECT dbo.Func('1001101')
```

**OUTPUT :**  `1:sunday 0:absent 0:absent 1:wednesday 1:thursday 0:absent 1:saturday`

**To get the final OUTPUT**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Funcfinal (@dayss VARCHAR(1000))
returns VARCHAR(1000)
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @cnt    INT =1,
              @outpt  VARCHAR(100),
              @fina   VARCHAR(100)='',
              @outpt1 VARCHAR(100)=''

      WHILE @cnt <= Len(@dayss)
        BEGIN
            SET @outpt = Substring(@dayss, @cnt, 1)

            SELECT @outpt1 = CASE
                               WHEN @outpt = 1 THEN Choose(@cnt, 'sunday ', 'monday ', 'tuesday ', 'wednesday ', 'thursday ', 'friday ', 'saturday ')
                               ELSE ''
                             END

            SET @fina += @outpt1
            SET @cnt+=1
        END

      RETURN @fina
  END

SELECT dbo.Funcfinal('1001101')
```

**OUTPUT :**   `sunday wednesday thursday saturday`

Comment: choose?? 
i am using 2012 version. but it is giving following error message.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure daysconvert, Line 17
'Choose' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @nishantnandgaonkar May be compatibility mode is set to `SQL SERVER 2008`. Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213019.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Traditional way of doing using CASE.

```
WHILE ( @i <= Len(@input) )
  BEGIN
      SET @temp = Substring(@input, @i, 1)
      SET @output += ' '+(SELECT CASE
                               WHEN @temp = 1
                                    AND @i = 1 THEN 'Sunday'
                               WHEN @temp = 1
                                    AND @i = 2 THEN 'Monday'
                               WHEN @temp = 1
                                    AND @i = 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
                               WHEN @temp = 1
                                    AND @i = 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
                               WHEN @temp = 1
                                    AND @i = 5 THEN 'Thursday'
                               WHEN @temp = 1
                                    AND @i = 6 THEN 'Friday'
                               WHEN @temp = 1
                                    AND @i = 7 THEN 'Saturday'
                               ELSE ''
                             END)
      SET @i = @i + 1

  END

PRINT @output
```